# DURING MODULES - typeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python

I was trying to calculate the greatest common divider of two random number, and here is my source code. The trackback shows that: 
`TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`But actually, I do not intend to do any string formatting. How should I correct it?

```
def gcd(Num_1, Num_2):
    c = (Num_1 % Num_2);
    Num_1 = Num_2;
    Num_2 = c;
    if c != 0:
        return gcd(Num_1, Num_2)
    else:
        return Num_1

Num_1 = raw_input("a\n>");
Num_2 = raw_input("b\n>");

gcd(Num_1, Num_2);
```

Comment: Check types of `Num_1` and `Num_2`.

Comment: i input two integer for `Num_1` and `Num_2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `raw_input()` to get an input, you get strings back, so `Num_1` and `Num_2` are strings, not int, hence when you use `%` on it, Python assumes its the string formatting operator, not the modules operator, and since there are no formats on the left side, you get the error. Example -

```
>>> '1' % '2'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

You should convert the inputs to `int` as you are expecting `int`. Also, there is an easier way to swap elements (what you are trying to do with the temporary variable) in Python -

```
def gcd(Num_1, Num_2):
    Num_1, Num_2 = Num_2, (Num_1 % Num_2)
    if c != 0:
        return gcd(Num_1, Num_2)
    else:
        return Num_1

Num_1 = int(raw_input("a\n>"))
Num_2 = int(raw_input("b\n>"))

gcd(Num_1, Num_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input` gives back a string and % on strings does string formatting.

Try using `input` instead: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=input#input

Comment: That really helps. I should use int() to convert it. Thank you soooooo much.